# The endpoints of the domain entered as a function in a `pgfplots` not recognized

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the graph of `y = 1/x` in a `tikzpicture` plotted to the right of text in a `minipage` environment.  I have `domain=-3:{-1/9}` for the part of the graph to be plotted over the set of negative real numbers, and I have `domain={1/9}:3` for the part of the graph to be plotted over the set of positive real numbers. The graph that is plotted is not symmetric across the origin, though.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{4.25in}
\begin{raggedright}
$f(x) = 1/x$ is a decreasing function over the interval $(-\infty, \, 0)$ and over the interval $(0, \, \infty)$, but $f$ is not a decreasing function. For every $0 < a < b$, since the product of positive numbers is a positive number, and since the reciprocal of a positive number is a positive number,
\begin{equation*}
f(b) = \frac{1}{b} = \left( \frac{1}{ab} \right) a < \left( \frac{1}{ab} \right) b = \frac{1}{a} = f(a) .
\end{equation*}
So, the restriction of $f$ to the set of positive real numbers is a decreasing function. Likewise, for every $m < n < 0$, since the product of negative numbers is a positive number,
\begin{equation*}
f(n) = \frac{1}{n} = \left( \frac{1}{mn} \right) m < \left( \frac{1}{mn} \right) n = \frac{1}{m} = f(m) .
\end{equation*}
So, the restriction of $f$ to the set of negative real numbers is a decreasing function. Though, $f$ is not a decreasing function. If $m < 0 < a$, since the reciprocal of a negative number is a negative number,
\begin{equation*}
f(m) = \frac{1}{m} < 0 < \frac{1}{a} = f(a) .
\end{equation*}
\end{raggedright}
\end{minipage}
%
\hspace{0.25cm}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\begin{axis}[height=2in, width=2in, clip=false,
    xmin=-3.5,xmax=3.5,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-9:9,
   % enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot [blue, domain=-3:{-1/9}] {1/x};
\addplot [blue, domain={1/9}:3] {1/x} node [pos=0, anchor=west, font=\tiny] {$y=\dfrac{1}{x}$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: fractions are problematic as usual with limited accuracy. Use `0.1111111111` or something like that

Comment: @percusse  I am curious why `domain={-1/9}:3` was interpreted properly but `domain={1/9}:3` was not.

Comment: Are you familiar with signed float precision? The positive one is actually the  correct one but out of the bounds. Try with `1/9+0.0001` for the lower bound on the positive side.

Comment: @percusse  Yes, I encoded `domain={1/9+0.0001}:3` and gives me the plot that I expected.

Comment: @percusse I am not familiar with "signed float precision." I guess that there was an error in rounding 1/9. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.